# Google is not returning my site until I search for my whole URL

Tags: google, google-search, search-engine-indexing

I created a sitemap, added my website for indexing on Google's console, but still my website is not showing in Google search results until I search for the whole URL of my website. Anyone know why it is happening? E.g. If my website is `example.com` then searching *example* does not show my website, but if I search for *example.com* then it works fine.

Comment: How long has it been since Google started indexing your site? Do you get the page returned if you search for an exact phrase on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Being indexed by Google does not guarantee that they will show your webpages in search results.

That may depend on several factors, such as the content quality or relevance of the search keywords.

In your case it seems that your site is already indexed but to be sure which pages are included in Google's index, do a search of the domain with the `site:` prefix, that will show you all the webpages currently indexed by Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com.

> The web is an organic, constantly shifting ecosystem, and your site’s
>   performance in search can change for many reasons. Maybe Google is
>   having problems crawling your site, or maybe there’s a problem with
>   your content.

Follow [these tips](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34444) to increase your website visibility in Google: [Check your site's search performance](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34444)